# x-frame-options laravel ¿Cómo configurar encabezados de seguridad para Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, web

buen día a todos

Estoy trabajando en laravel y en este momento estoy validando la parte de seguridad

utilizando esta pagina https://securityheaders.com/ para validar la seguridad

cuando la escaneo me da varios puntos uno de ellos es

**X-Frame-Options**

lo marca con una **X** y exactamente no se se a que se refiere, he buscado información pero lo que encuentro es para realizar consultas a la BD, y no termino de comprender que es lo que realmente tengo que realizar por que no realizo ninguna consulta en la pagina que estoy inspeccionado.

alguien podría guiarme?

saludos

Comment: Puedes usar esta librería https://github.com/BePsvPT/secure-headers

Comment: la voy a revisar ya tengo por donde iniciar mi búsqueda gracias

Comment: De nada, la cabecera `x-frame-options` no tiene nada que ver con la base de datos, lo que hace es especificar si permites que tu sitio sea "frameado" en otro sitio, el valor recomendado es `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN`

Answer (score 4):

Si no pudiste instalar la librería que te comenté, te dejo la solución manual:

Crear un archivo dentro de `app/Http/Middleware/` y le puedes poner el nombre que sea que llevará tu clase, yo le pondré `HeadersSeguros.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class HeadersSeguros
{
    // Podrías checar la siguiente página para más información acerca de estas cabeceras
    // https://securityheaders.com/

    // Lista las cabeceras que no quieras en tus respuestas de tu aplicación
    // Hay cabeceras que no es recomendable que se muestren, por ejemplo "X-Powered-BY" muestra información del servidor, la puedes editar a tu gusto
    private $headersNoAdmitidos = [
        'X-Powered-By',
        'Server',
    ];
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->removerCabecerasNoAdmitidas($this->headersNoAdmitidos);
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Referrer-Policy', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade');
        $response->headers->set('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
        $response->headers->set('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
        $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
        $response->headers->set('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age:31536000; includeSubDomains');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"); // Esta cabecera si depende mucho de tu aplicación (Leer más después del código)
        return $response;
    }
    private function removerCabecerasNoAdmitidas($listaCabeceras)
    {
        foreach ($listaCabeceras as $cabecera)
            header_remove($cabecera);
    }
}
```

Después de añadir este código, te vas a tu `Kernel` (`app/Http/Kernel.php`) para registrar la clase, dentro de la variable `$middleware` agregas lo siguiente:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\HeadersSeguros::class,
```

Sugiero que le eches una leída a la cabecera llamada `Content-Security-Policy`. En resumen, esta cabecera reduce el riesgo de ataques [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) de manera que tu le puedes especificar de donde pueden cargar los recursos de tu aplicación web.

En el ejemplo que yo te puse de esta cabecera que te menciono le estás diciendo con la palabra `self` que las fuentes de estilos (archivos css externos) sólo los puede cargar desde tu propia aplicación y con la palabra `unsafe-inline` que permites estilos "en línea" (se consideran estilos en línea al código CSS dentro de las etiquetas `<style></style>`) que sean cargados, y no es seguro cargar estilos en línea, la palabra lo dice. Se utilizan las comillas simples para estas palabras reservadas. Después se encuentra un `;` para separar directivas, a continuación se especifican las mismas reglas pero ahora para fuentes javascript. Si tienes código en línea dentro de etiquetas `<script></script>` y quieres sacar la más alta calificación, te recomiendo lo quites de tu archivo `html` o `php` y las pongas en un archivo `.js` aparte, de lo contrario se toma como inseguro y la página en dónde estás checando no te pondrá "A+" de calificación.

Si quieres cargar fuentes por decir de fuentes como cdn y de google, la directiva quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://www.google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://www.google.com");
```

Los dominios se listan de forma continua separadas de un espacio en blanco.

Comment: Me funciono correctamente la primera opción pero voy a realizar esta opción, muchas gracias por la explicación me quedo claro los otros puntos que tocaste.